Literature check for a summation formula
In this paper I did a lot of stuff relating to sums, including a formula for explicitly evaluating them near the end of the paper:

Let $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_kx^k$ be the power series of $f(x)$. Then $$\sum_{k=1}^xf(k)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{c_i}{i+1}\sum_{k=0}^iB_kx^{i-k+1}$$Where $B_k$ denote the Bernoulli numbers with $B_1=\frac12$.

I was just wondering if this formula was already found since it isn't too complicated and neither was the proof (replace $f$ with its power series, then use Faulhaber's formula after swapping the sum notations).
